# How to create a dynamic object from JSON that itself contains the structure of that object

Tags: c#, json.net

There is a nice function in json.net to convert a json into a c# object:

```
CMyObject myObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CMyObject>(json);
```

Problem with that is that the structure needs to be known upfront.

Is there a lean way if the structre itself is coming from json itself?

Here an example of the json:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "255622": {
      "2": {
        "value": "Active"
      },
      "3": {
        "value": null
      }
    }
  },

  "schema": {
    "255622": {
      "name": "NameOfStructure",
      "properties": {
        "2": {
          "multi_value": false,
          "name": "Status",
          "type_name": "String"
        },
        "3": {
          "multi_value": false,
          "name": "StatusDate",
          "type_name": "Date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should convert to:

```
myObject (type NameOfStructure)
myObject.Status = "Active" (type String - single value)
myObject.StatusDate = null (type Date - single value)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What you want is probably not useful. Think about it: What would you do with an object tree of types and fields you don't know? You can't reference them in code, can't allocate any variables for them etc.

Comment: With [json.net schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) you could verify the `data` against `schema`.

Answer (score 2):

actually I am pretty sure you can do that with the dynamic keyword.

I can't check right now but you should be able to do something like :

```
dynamic myObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

or something along those lines, this is sometimes useful as you can still parse the tree for whatever you need or discover what the types are and then do something with that information, depending on your use case.

I also used another approach in the past with an ExpandoObject instead of dynamic.

It depends what your use case is, but those are the approaches I'd investigate more

Comment: See also: `JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType` where you provide a "template" object that Json.NET populates.

Answer (score 0):

With [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can easily do like this:

```
dynamic myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

The result will be dynamic so you can reach any property by

```
var myField = myObject.data.yourJsonfield;
```

Also same with **using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq:**

```
dynamic myObject = JObject.Parse(json);
```

You can find more information [here.](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm)